# I can not find the click event in href="#"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm going through a list to click on the Alquilar button found in  Alquilar

```html
<ul id="vertical-operation-menu">
  <li valorTipoHome="1" id="home-Venta" class="js-btn-home current vertical-operation-menu-btns">
    <a href="#">Comprar</a>
  </li>
  <li valorTipoHome="2" id="home-Alquiler" class="js-btn-home  vertical-operation-menu-btns">
    <a href="#">Alquilar</a>
  </li>
  <li valorTipoHome="desarrollosURL" id="home-Emprendimiento" class="js-btn-home  vertical-operation-menu-btns">
    <a href="#">Emprendimientos</a>
  </li>
  <li valorTipoHome="homeComercial_grupo_4" data-tipo-propiedad-dfp="4,5,10,8,45" id="home-Comercial" class="js-btn-home  vertical-operation-menu-btns">
    <a href="#">Comercial</a>
  </li>
  <li valorTipoHome="4" id="home-Vacacional" class="js-btn-home  vertical-operation-menu-btns">
    <a href="#">Temporal</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am capturing it with XPATH in the following way

```
tipoOperacion = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home-Alquiler"]/a')
tipoOperacion.click()
```

but nothing happens

look at the data that I am capturing and return the name of the button

```
a = tipoOperacion.text
print(a)
```

> ALQUILAR

But I can not click on the button

I add an answer to the question
    print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Alquilar']"))).text)

> ALQUILAR

Comment: Did you try clicking the parent element instead of the link?

Comment: @Guy I do not probe it, how would it be?

Comment: `tipoOperacion = webdriver.find_element_by_id('home-Alquiler')`

Comment: @Guy 
it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this see if it helps.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Alquilar']"))).click()
```

note:
use following imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**EDIT:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
 element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Alquilar']")
 ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

OR

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Alquilar']"))
```

Comment: could you check that if there any `iframe` pressent in your html?

Comment: there is no iframe

Comment: can you share the url if possible?

Comment: are you able to print the value : `print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Alquilar']"))).text)`

Comment: @Sebastian : check edidted one.Probably webdriver click is not working